# /Fabric.framework/run: No such file or directory Xcode7

Tags: xcode7

how can I fix this ?

/Users/MyName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProName-flnujrubzrsocdfudhdqzvrueima/Build/Intermediates/MyProName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProName.build/Script-6F5256511BB54D93005685FE.sh: line 2: ./Fabric.framework/run: No such file or directory

I try to add again the twitter sdk but isn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

you should remove the fabric script from run script

Comment: But what happens if you need it on the run script?

Comment: @ asafbar can you explain more how to do that ?

Comment: You might not want to remove it since it's there for a reason, to notify Fabric that your build succeeded

Comment: Putting it in the run script is exactly what the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started-new-sdk?platform=ios&authuser=0) says to do.

Comment: My project is a React Native project and  I am using React-native-firebase Crashlytics. Should I delete the run script as well ?

Answer (score 29):

For anyone having this issue that's a first timer with Crashlytics like myself

On Xcode 8.0, all I did was change my path in the build run script to:

> *"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run"*

For some reason my run script was nested under Fabric.framework. That fixes the build failed issue.

Comment: That was the problem! I change the value inside **TARGETS => Build Phases => Run Script** from `./Fabric.framework/run OneLongIdentify AnotherLongLongLongIdentify` to `${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run OneLongIdentify AnotherLongLongLongIdentify` and it works!! Thank you mate

Comment: On Xcode 10.0, I had to change the path to `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/iOS/Fabric.framework/run"`

Comment: @Sal: I'm facing this issue, may I know what is `${PODS_ROOT}` ?

Comment: @Isaac: `${PODS_ROOT}` is the root directory of your Cocoapods - if you installed Fabric using Cocoapods.

Comment: tried "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/iOS/Fabric.framework/run" gives error Pods/Fabric/uploadDSYM: No such file or directory am using xcode 9.4.1

Comment: Thanks, fixed my error was stuck on this for an hour

Answer (score 9):

Short version.

If you used a tool that may have changed the fabric framework path change the run script path to where is the fabric.framework is. Probably crashlytics framework should be in same directory.

Okay let me tell you my story.
One faithful night I found a tool called **Synx** (https://github.com/venmo/synx). Which give a certain promise to tired Xcode developers like me. "Tool that reorganizes your Xcode project folder to match your Xcode groups.".

I checked my 400 something class project folder.
Then look my Xcode group hierarchy.
Then look at my project folder once again.
It was abysmal. Totally chaotic. So I thought, what can I lose... Right?

Tempted by Satan himself, I, a half sleep developer, started to install plug in (Heart BPM:100)...

Opening terminal (Heart BPM:120)

Entering the project's path (Heart BPM:90 due to entering the project's path wrong numerous times)

Hitting return key (Heart BPM:160)

Logs are flowing like beautiful waterfall (not the software development process, I mean the other one. We still hate that, right guys?)

After 5-6 seconds everything was finished. Clicked finder, went to project folder, and there it was, like a delicious untouched cheesecake. Perfect in every way.

But a senior developer like me won't be happy... yet...

Opened Xcode, hit run... And there it is. Hello "Build Failed" my old friend.

After fixing a couple of Alias problems (it means shortcut for fellow windows users) hit run again.

This time it takes a long time... Good sign.

Then have this error .Fabric.framework/run: No such file or directory

Okay it is 2 am. I shouldn't start panicking right... Wrong...
Did I make a copy of the project... No.
When was my last github push... a week ago at best.

Lets clean the project. Done. Try again... A Big Fat No.
Okay then reinstall fabric. But I can't remove the .framework files. I have so many Answer SDK calls that removing them will take ages. Alright just remove Build Phase -> Run Script. Compile... Working at last; without our primary (and only) way to over-the-air installation.

Okay, no problem, reinstalling is easy right? This is the fabric we talking about.

With extreme pessimism, I, opened the fabric desktop app find my way through Crashlytics. Clicked install button (Which should be renamed reinstall in my humble opinion.) and stuck with "Command + B" stage. Nothing happens.

After opening and closing Xcode and/or fabric desktop app. Restarting mac... Cleaning build folder I understood that it was... not the way I should be taking.

After cursing, watching something to calm my nerves (friends, season 4), at 3 AM, I had a revelation. Run script probably pointing wrong path since Synx probably changed the .framework files' path.

This time I was right. Got the old Run Script String from github (the latest push was 2 weeks old by the way /Note to self : Don't do this again. Daily pushes... You are not an idiot.). Changed the path and...

Voilà

Right now I didn't try the app fully, but everything compiled and running.
as Orson Welles said

> If you want a happy ending, that depends, of course, on where you stop
>   your story.

So here it is.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Delete this line here to stop the script from running.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution for those who using Unity plugin instead of pods

Replace

```
./Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Fabric/Fabric.framework/...
```

With:

```
./Frameworks/Fabric.framework/...
```

In case if path will change again, try to look for it in Frameworks folder of the project:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It may prove help full

In my case the path was wrong.
Go to build settings under run scripts the path was 
./Fabric.framework/run "key"
 but when I change it to ./myProjectName/Fabric.framework/run everything worked fine.

Actually the Framework was inside "myProject" folder. So in my case giving the right path solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing X code You will get same error. So You need to remove run-script and re install again.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error if you haven't run `pod install` since adding `pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'` to your Podfile because the script can't find a file that hasn't been installed yet.